# Number of Games in the Upcoming World Classical Chess Championship: Comparison with Previous Championships

Tags: history, tournament, grandmaster, world-championship, famous-players

I'm curious about the format of the upcoming World Classical Chess Championship. Historically, the number of games in these championships has varied. For instance, the Carlsen-Karjakin championship in 2016 featured 12 games, while the recent Ding-Nepo championship had 14 games.

Given these variations, I'm interested in knowing how many games are planned for the next World Classical Chess Championship. Understanding this could provide insights into the strategies and preparations of the players involved.

Answer (score 2):

The format will be a best of 14 games. There will be tie breaks if required. [Source](https://wcc.fide.com/cycle2023_2024.phtml)

The format has been formalised by FIDE, so I wouldn't be anticipating significant changes for at least another 2 to 3 championship match ups. It's either that, or serious chess drama unfolds, which is always a possibility.

Sadly, we wont be seeing any epics like Karpov v Korchnoi in 1978, which went for 32 games, anytime soon.